# collections for domain objects - composition vs. inheritance

Tags: java, oop

I've recently been experimenting with extending collection objects instead of using composition for my domain objects. So for example I will use this:

```
public class Path extends ArrayList<PathElement> {
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  Path path = new Path();
  path.add(new PathElement());
}
```

instead of:

```
public class Path {
  private List<PathElement> pathElements = new ArrayList<PathElement>();

  /* getter/setter*/

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  Path path = new Path();
  path.getPathElements().add(new PathElement());
}
```

Is this a common/acceptable practice? Are there any drawbacks or better alternatives? One drawback I can see is that the implementation cannot be changed easily, so you cannot for example use a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList.

Comment: IMHO second approach is less intuitive. Anyway, I believe you should start with designing your interface first, not implementation. This will direct you the right way.

Comment: I don't like first approach because I think inherit some existing collection (not interface) is not good choice. You can broke existing collection methods by overriding some vital methods. I agree with @Andy that you need to design interface first.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by design interface first.

Comment: Yes, it is true that you can break functionality easily. An advantage, though, in my experience is that it results in much cleaner code, especially in cases of multiple nested collections.

Comment: When you design an application you create design first, class diagram. Only then you start implementing it. First you should think WHAT you need, instead HOW to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach is correct. You shouldn't be extending the built-in data structure classes unless you are modifying their behavior or adding new behavior.

Even if you modify or add new behavior, your domain objects shouldn't be extending them. Instead, create a separate class which extends the Map or List and use the new class in your domain object, as you shown in second code block.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've been experimenting lately with more "domain-driven design", but I see that this approach is not actually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is definitely the wrong way.
You should be using composition and not inheritence. Inheritence "breaks" encapsulation and couples with implementation details if not done correctly. Meaning you should only extend classes under your control and designed for extension. Otherwise you can get into a mess of troubles